# Is there any other idiomatic ways to pass state information?

Tags: f#

I have a need to process a sequence of historical tick data of millisecond timeframe. The ability is required to filter in opening ticks of certain timespans (hourly, minute, etc.). The sequence may have gaps greater, than the span, so the first tick after such gap must be picked as opening one, otherwise the opening tick is one that is closest to pass of calendar beginning of correspondent timespan.

The first thing that comes to my mind is the following **stateful** filtering function `opensTimespan:Timespan->(Timestamp->bool)` that captures timespanId of each gap-opening or interval-opening tick into a closure for passing between invocations:

```
let opensTimespan (interval: Timespan)=
    let lastTakenId = ref -1L  // Timestamps are positive
    fun (tickAt: Timestamp) -> 
        let tickId = tickAt / interval in
            if tickId <> !lastTakenId then lastTakenId := tickId; true
            else false
```

and can be applied like this:

```
let hourlyTicks = readTicks @"EURUSD-history.zip" "EURUSD-2012-04.csv"
                  |> Seq.filter (opensTimespan HOUR) |> Seq.toList
```

This works fine, but `opensTimespan` having the side effect is definitely not idiomatic.

One alternative may be using the fact that the decision upon a tick is opening one or not requires just the pair of timestamps of the self and the previous one to come up with the following **stateless** filtering function `opensTimespanF:Timespan->Timestamp*Timestamp->bool`:

```
let opensTimespanF interval (ticksPair: Timestamp*Timestamp) =
    fst ticksPair/ interval <> snd ticksPair/ interval
```

that can be applied as:

```
let hourlyTicks= 
    seq {
        yield 0L;
        yield! readTicks @"EURUSD-history.zip" "EURUSD-2012-04.csv"
    }
    |> Seq.pairwise |> Seq.filter (opensTimespanF HOUR)
    |> Seq.map snd
    |> Seq.toList
```

This approach being pure functional produces equivalent results with only a slight (~11%) performance penalty.

What other way(s) of approaching this task in pure functional manner I may be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: I'd say that if the side effect is confined within the opensTimespan function, it may not be 'idiomatic', but it's certainly acceptable for performance. Core F# functions do the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A purely functional solution would be to use the `fold` function. The `fold` function is used to process a sequence (or a list) and accumulate some state. In your example, the state is the `lastTakenId` and also the list of elements that you want to return, so you can use state of type `Timestamp * (Timestamp list)`:

```
let hourlyTicks = 
  readTicks @"EURUSD-history.zip" "EURUSD-2012-04.csv" 
  |> Seq.fold (fun (lastTakenId, res) tickAt ->
      // Similar to the body of your stateful function - 'lastTakenId' is the last
      // state and 'tickAt' is the current value. The 'res' list stores 
      // all returned elements
      let tickId = tickAt / HOUR 
      if tickId <> lastTakenId then  
        // We return new state for 'lastTakenId' and append current element to result
        (tickId, tickAt::res)
      else 
        // Here, we skip element, so we return the original state and original list
        (lastTakenId, res) ) (-1L, []) // Initial state: -1 and empty list of results

  // Take the second part of the state (the result list) and
  // reverse it, because it was accumulated in the opposite order
  |> snd |> List.rev
```

Aside, I'm not entirely sure about your other pure solution - I don't think it does exactly the same thing as the first one (but I don't have the data to test), because you're only comparing two adjacent elements (so, perhaps, in the first one, you may skip multiple items?)

Comment: Tomas, both my solutions (and yours and Stephen's as well) are equivalent result-wise and against my unit tests. Yours is VERY effective timewise - it adds only 4% to mines stateful. Although meanwhile I improved mines by switching from sliding window to comparing tick tuples via `Seq.pairwise` it still carries 11% time
penalty. My only concern is space consideration - test data are ~8mil worth of ticks yielding 507 hourly. It would be interesting to see if intermediate list and the need of reverse would adversely affect your suggestion if being applied to few years of tick data.

Answer (score 5):

Like Tomas' solution (indeed, I used his as my starting point, comments and all), except using [Seq.scan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340364.aspx) which allows you to avoid `List.rev` and yields results on demand (so, we could handle infinite tick streams, for example).

```
let hourlyTicks = 
  readTicks @"EURUSD-history.zip" "EURUSD-2012-04.csv" 
  |> Seq.scan (fun (lastTakenId,_) tickAt ->
      // Similar to the body of your stateful function - 'lastTakenId' is the last state
      // and 'tickAt' is the current value.
      let tickId = tickAt / HOUR 
      if tickId <> lastTakenId then  
        // We return new state for 'lastTakenId' and yield current 
        // element to the "scan stream"
        (tickId, Some(tickAt))
      else 
        // Here, we skip element, so we return the original tick id and 
        // yield None to the "scan stream"
        (lastTakenId, None) ) (-1L, None) // Initial state: -1 and None

  //yield all the snd elements of the "scan stream" where Option.isSome
  |> Seq.choose snd
```

(disclaimer: I did not test this since I don't have all the dependencies assumed in your question).

**Update in response to comment**

I wonder if the performance penalty you are seeing is due to boxing / unboxing the values in the accumulator. I'd be interested to hear whether the following shows an improvement:

```
open System
open System.Collections.Generic
let hourlyTicks3 = 
  readTicks @"EURUSD-history.zip" "EURUSD-2012-04.csv" 
  |> Seq.scan (fun (kvp:KeyValuePair<_,_>) tickAt ->
      let lastTakenId = kvp.Key
      // Similar to the body of your stateful function - 'lastTakenId' is the last state
      // and 'tickAt' is the current value.
      let tickId = tickAt / HOUR 
      if tickId <> lastTakenId then  
        // We return new state for 'lastTakenId' and yield current 
        // element to the "scan stream"
        KeyValuePair<_,_>(tickId, Nullable<_>(tickAt))
      else 
        // Here, we skip element, so we return the original tick id and 
        // yield "null" to the "scan stream"
        KeyValuePair<_,_>(lastTakenId, Nullable<_>()) ) (KeyValuePair<_,_>(-1L, Nullable<_>())) // Initial state: -1 and "null"
  //yield all Values of KeyValuePair.Value elements of the "scan stream" where Nullable.HasValue
  |> Seq.filter (fun kvp -> kvp.Value.HasValue)
  |> Seq.map (fun kvp -> kvp.Value.Value)
```

Comment: Stephen, very beautiful application of `Seq.scan`!  However, it carries a substantial performance penalty. For comparison I've appended `Seq.toList` (like in both my original takes that are also
sequence-based) and it yielded whopping 28% increase over the stateful, compared to only 4% of Tomas' fold-based.

Comment: @GeneBelitski - Thanks! I added an update to my answer with an idea for a performance improvement.

Comment: Yes, time has improved and is now on par with my original stateless ~15% time penalty (I moved to `Seq.pairwise` from `Seq.windowed 2` since, which shaved ~4% penalty). Likely
you are right about extra boxing/unboxing cause as I can observe noticeably less gen0 GC now.
Thank you!